# Ubuntu 20.04 sound doesn't start, but it works in the old live DVD Linux

Tags: audio, ubuntu-20.04, alsa, pulseaudio, soundcard

**Attention!** It's not a duplicate, because I've used suggestions from those articles, and those suggestions worked intermittently at first, but now they stopped working whatsoever.

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, my sound card stopped working on boot.
I've found a solution, that works only, when you do it manualy after each boot and only, pretty much, right after the greeting GUI screen loads (wuthout logging in to the desktop) and can't wait for too long, otherwise, it will not work (it's time sensitive). I have to do it by switching from the GUI greeting to the TTY screen and do the following:

```
pulseaudio -k && sleep 1 && sudo alsa force-reload && pulseaudio --start
```

Without it, the system loads with the dummy sound device.
The command above, doesn't always work, sometimes, you have to run it several times in order for it to kick in. Sometimes, it doesn't work, no matter how many times, you try, so I reboot and try again. (I check by playing a sound file after each try):

```
play sound.mp3
```

But recently, it stopped working whatsoever.
I tried loading to different kernels, but it doesn't help.
I thought, that my sound card just broke, but i tested it by loading an old live DVD with Linux Mint 17 and checked - the sound worked. I played some sounds from that live system.
Then, I rebooted back to my system.
Tried to purge (removed with configs) everything, that said alsa and everything, that said pulse, then reinstalled the removed packages back again. Still no work.

Please, masters, experienced with Linux sound system, help me to solve my problem.

Comment: does sound work when you boot from the LiveUSB memory stick ?   meaning download Ubuntu iso file then burn it onto a memory stick then book from that USB stick ... benefit here is all code is working as tested and if you get sound using that then problem is your install probably some conflicting packages or manual changes you have made ... alternative to using a USB stick you can burn the iso onto a DVD if desired

Comment: Yes, as I wrote in my question text, I tried to test it with the old live DVD and the sound worked. Manual changes don't apply also, because, as I wrote in my question, I tried to purge Alsa and Pulse with removing all of related configs, while purging and reinstalled them again. I need help figuring out how to fix it without reinstalling an OS and everything else from scratch. I would prefer to use a scalpel to fix the problem once and for all and not destroy everything with the sledge hummer and rebuild it from scratch.

Comment: nothing of value I keep local to my linux laptop ... I use MEGA nz for  cloud file storage or dropbox or github.com or ...  I suggest you do something similar ... then as you say your computer plays audio fine when booted from LiveDVD so your hardware is fine and issue is software and/or config ... once all backed up I suggest you do a fresh install not an upgrade and reinstall Ubuntu  ... yes sometime we need to throw our hands up and drop kick

Comment: Yes, removing everything and reinstalling again is a really long, but dirty solution, that will probably solve the issue, but I pursue to find out how to fix it without reinstalling everything, when I stumble on it again. The same way, you can't just keep reinstalling everything every time you have one problem, that needs to be fixed. You need to find the solution and use it. Reinstalling everything for each problem is a Windows way, although, I've never done it on Windows either. I need to find a solution, not destroy everything to the ground and build it again.

Comment: keep in mind an OS upgrade inherits much from the prior OS ... it undoes some local config changes by far not all changes in preparation for the upgrade ... its almost a rite of passage to mess around with audio enough to break it where its easier to do the full reinstall and on next adventure to take notes as to each audio related change made to make it easier to fix

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue just like this. I even reinstall, but it's not solve. Until some page in internet, not in this web, give me this:

```
alsamixer
```

just type this in terminal and you will have pop up about volume. At this point, add volume with arrow up, then hopefully it will solve